# Google translations and copyright

Tags: copyright

I want to translate Turkish sentences through Google Translate for the purpose of using it in a work. Is this subject to copyright?

Comment: If the original sentences are subject to copyright, then so is the translation. You can't "wash away" the copyright by translating it.

Answer (score 2):

The "creativity" that goes into a Google translation is the program itself, which is protected by copyright. GT just provides an automated mapping from one language to another, and is legally equivalent to printing a Word document (the printed copy doesn't gain its own copyright).

The original that you feed in might be protected, however. If so, so is the translation.